# Conditional sum data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have an R data frame with many columns, and I want to sum only columns (header: score) having either cell value >25 or >-25 under row named "Matt". The sum value can be placed after the last column.

```
input (df1)
```

| Name | score | score | score | score | score | score | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 31 | 15 | 18 | 22 | 23 | 23 | 23 |
| Pat | 37 | 18 | 29 | 15 | 28 | 28 | -28 |
| Matt | 33 | 27 | 18 | 88 | 9 | -19 | -29 |
| James | 12 | -36 | 32 | 13 | 21 | 21 | 21 |

```
output (df2)
```

| Name | score | score | score | score | score | acore | score | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 31 | 15 | 18 | 22 | 23 | 23 | 23 | 91 |
| Pat | 37 | 18 | 29 | 15 | 28 | 28 | -28 | 42 |
| Matt | 33 | 27 | 18 | 88 | 9 | -19 | -29 | 119 |
| James | 12 | -36 | 32 | 13 | 21 | 21 | 21 | 10 |

Any thoughts are more than welcome,

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a logical vector based on the 'Name' column ('i1'), then use the OR (`|` condition on the value 25 and -25 with relational operators (`>` or `<` respectively) to create a logical index for the columns.  Subset the dataset based on the 'i2', and return the `rowSums` of those columns and assign it to 'sum' column

```
i1 <-df1$Name == "Matt" 

i2 <- df1[i1,-1] > 25|df1[i1,-1] < -25
df1$sum <- rowSums(df1[-1][,i2], na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Matt = rowSums(select(cur_data(), 
            where(~ is.numeric(.) &&
          (.[Name == 'Matt'] > 25| .[Name == 'Matt'] < -25)))))
```

-output

```
#    Name score score.1 score.2 score.3 score.4 score.5 score.6 Matt
#1  Alex    31      15      18      22      23      23      23   91
#2   Pat    37      18      29      15      28      28     -28   42
#3  Matt    33      27      18      88       9     -19     -29  119
#4 James    12     -36      32      13      21      21      21   10
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you can solve it in the tidyverse, I use convert it to a longer format so it is easier to deal with it, then we bring it back using a left join

```r
library(tidyverse)

data_example <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Name, ~score1, ~score2, ~score3, ~score4, ~score5, ~score6, ~score7, ~sum,
   "Alex",    31L,    15L,    18L,    22L,    23L,    23L,    23L,  91L,
    "Pat",    37L,    18L,    29L,    15L,    28L,    28L,   -28L,  42L,
   "Matt",    33L,    27L,    18L,    88L,     9L,   -19L,   -29L, 119L,
  "James",    12L,   -36L,    32L,    13L,    21L,    21L,    21L,  10L
  )

valid_condition <- function(x) if_else(x >=25|x<= -25,true = x,false = 0L)

result <- data_example |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("score"),names_to = "score_name",values_to = "score_value") |> 
  group_by(score_name) |> 
  filter(score_value[Name == "Matt"] >25|score_value[Name == "Matt"] < -25) |> 
  group_by(Name) |> 
  summarise(final_sum = sum(score_value))

  
data_example |>
  left_join(result)
#> Joining, by = "Name"
#> # A tibble: 4 x 10
#>   Name  score1 score2 score3 score4 score5 score6 score7   sum final_sum
#>   <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int> <int>     <int>
#> 1 Alex      31     15     18     22     23     23     23    91        91
#> 2 Pat       37     18     29     15     28     28    -28    42        42
#> 3 Matt      33     27     18     88      9    -19    -29   119       119
#> 4 James     12    -36     32     13     21     21     21    10        10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I've never seen |> used and can't find any information about it, but I assume it's equivalent to the pipe operator %>% ? It doesn't work for me on Windows 10, is this another OS or different package or something?

Comment: It is the new base r pipe operator you need r 4.1 to use it